# Mix Columns in AES cryptography Algorithm

Tags: aes

Hi I am totally new to cryptography.
This paper [1] was explaining the mix columns. But at a point I am not understanding the calculation.

F2 * 03 = F2 *02 + F2 * 01

= 1111 0010 *02 = 11100101 XOR 1B = 11100101

XOR 0001 1011

F2 *02 = 1111 1111

how come 11100101 XOR 00011011 = 1111 1111 ? isn't it 1111 1110
Can anyone explain me this. Please???

[1]https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ako-Abdullah/publication/317615794_Advanced_Encryption_Standard_AES_Algorithm_to_Encrypt_and_Decrypt_Data/links/59437cd8a6fdccb93ab28a48/Advanced-Encryption-Standard-AES-Algorithm-to-Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Data.pdf

Answer (score 5):

[This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ako-Abdullah/publication/317615794_Advanced_Encryption_Standard_AES_Algorithm_to_Encrypt_and_Decrypt_Data/links/59437cd8a6fdccb93ab28a48/Advanced-Encryption-Standard-AES-Algorithm-to-Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Data.pdf#page=2) is of the kind written to be made, not read. Except for increasing the knowledge of it's author, and the citation count of other papers, it's pointless. **Importantly: in the future, don't trust whatever made you read this paper**. Learn AES from another source. One option is to look at the [defining paper](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/documents/aes-development/rijndael-ammended.pdf#page=3).

That `= 1111 0010 *02 = 11100101 XOR 1B = 11100101 XOR 0001 1011` is disconnected from the rest, and locally wrong.

Actually, `F2*02` can be computed as `11110010 << 1` reduced modulo $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ (represented as `100011011`) per binary polynomial arithmetic, that is `111100100 ⊕ 100011011`, that is `011111111`, that is byte `FF`.

Comment: Thank you so much... It is a great help...